# How to change target framework of a .net core project from netstandard2.1 to netcoreapp3.1 in VS Code

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-code, reference

I have a web app solution created on vs code, in which I have 4 project.
One project, named "core.csproj" is targeted framework as: netstandard2.1

All the rest (API.csproj, infrastructure.csproj, emailservice.csproj) are targeted at 3.1 as:
netcoreapp3.1**

Now, I encountered incompatible problem when I tried to add the "core.csproj" as reference project to other projects. Therefore, I wanted to change it. Can anyone please guide how?

The dotnet command I used to add reference project:
dotnet add Core/Core.csproj reference API/API.csproj

The Error I got:
API.csproj cannot be added due to incompatible targeted frameworks between the two projects. Review the project you are trying to add and verify that is compatible with the following targets: - unsupported.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit the **core.csproj file** and change the `TargetFramework` property to 3.1. and save the file.

Rebuild the solution, if any errors result correct them.

Rebuild again.

Please take a backup of the project before you do change for any unexpected problem risk.

Example here:

[image: core.csproj]

Comment: I run dotnet build after making this change. got Build FAILED. 
Determining projects to restore...
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.101\NuGet.targets(131,5): error : Invalid restore input. Invalid target framework 'unsupported'.

Comment: @canbrian , it is expected to have some errors that need to be solved related to code compatibility. so you need to go through these errors one by one and solve them.

Comment: @canbrian especially related to Nugets packages if used, maybe they need to be updated as well.

Comment: This is all the error message. "Determining projects to restore... C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.101\NuGet.targets(131,5): error : Invalid restore input. Invalid target framework 'unsupported'.

Comment: @canbrian are you using .NET 5?

Comment: yes, .NET 5. I've successfully build it now. I believe the way of changing target framework works. Thanks for your help!

Comment: great! happy about that